# Problema de inserir no banco de dados - SQL

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc-5, sql-insert

Segue o código:

Comando Update funciona:

```
int noOfRowUpdated = ctx.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("Update Mapa set Geo = geography::Point(47.65100, -122.34900, 4326) where Id= 1");
```

O que não funciona é comando insert:

```
int noOfRowInserted = ctx.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("INSERT into Mapa(Geo) values('geography::Point(47.65100, -122.34900, 4326)')");
```

Recebo esse erro:

> A .NET Framework error occurred during execution of user-defined
>   routine or aggregate "geography":  System.FormatException: 24114: o
>   rótulo geography::Point(47. no WKT (well-known text) de entrada não é
>   válido. Rótulos válidos são: POINT, LINESTRING, POLYGON, MULTIPOINT,
>   MULTILINESTRING, MULTIPOLYGON, GEOMETRYCOLLECTION, CIRCULARSTRING,
>   COMPOUNDCURVE, CURVEPOLYGON e FULLGLOBE (apenas Tipo de Dados
>   geography). System.FormatException:    em
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.OpenGisTypes.ParseLabel(String input)   em
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.WellKnownTextReader.ParseTaggedText(OpenGisType
>   type)   em
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.WellKnownTextReader.Read(OpenGisType type,
>   Int32 srid)   em
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SqlGeography.ParseText(OpenGisType type,
>   SqlChars taggedText, Int32 srid)   em
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SqlGeography.GeographyFromText(OpenGisType
>   type, SqlChars taggedText, Int32 srid)   em
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SqlGeography.Parse(SqlString s) . The
>   statement has been terminated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As aspas simples têm que começar antes do `('Point(...` não antes de `geography::`. Se não, tente removê-las.

Como [neste exemplo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/cc280766.aspx) da Microsoft:

```html
.
.
.

INSERT INTO SpatialTable (GeogCol1)  
VALUES (geography::STGeomFromText('LINESTRING(-122.360 47.656, -122.343 47.656 )', 4326));

.
.
.
```

Viu só?! Nada de aspas envolvendo a palavra-chave *geography*.